# UnsatisfiedLinkError when using JNI?

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface

I want to call a C program from Java program using JNI in linux ubuntu.

I am new to this and I have tried the sample program given in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/section2.html
. I have already created the .java, .h , .c and .so files. But when i tried to run the program I am getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Sample1 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:13)
```

Comment: It is missing something called "Sample1". Ensure the shared object is built and in the indicated path.

Comment: @poonam Hoshi: Please write the steps used in creating the sharelibrary and command line/LD_LIBRARY_PATH  used to pass the library to jvm..

Comment: Where is you libSample.so and whatis your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 3):

This exception is indicating that the `.so` is not available to the JVM.

Adding the directory where the `.so` exists to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will resolve this. If the `.so` depends on other `.so` libraries the directories where these `.so` exist will also need added to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I tried setting the library path but it is still not working. My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS. I just learned from some other site that in this version of ubuntu LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesnot work anymore.Please help resolving this. and Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried to get the same sample to work on my CentOS and got the same error as you. As already answered, JVM failed to find the so file needed. I succeeded to get it to work by following the steps below using gcc:

```
$ javac Sample1.java
$ javah Sample1
$ # Include paths must also be specified using -I option in the following gcc command line!
$ gcc -shared -I...snip... Sample1.c -o libSample1.so
$ # Library path for libSample1.so must also be specified!
$ java -Djava.library.path=...path/to/libSample1.so... Sample1
```

If you omit the "lib" prefix of the shared library, JVM fails to find it for some reason.
I don't know why. I am not familiar with the naming convention of shared libraries in Linux.

I hope this post could help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i am still not able to resolve the error. My ubuntu version is Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS.

Comment: In "-Djava.library.path=..." only the path to libSample1.so, without the lib itself!