# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (Library not found despite being in java.lang.path)

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, java

I am working on a 64bit Linux machine. I am trying to emulate a simple JNI tutorial given [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html). After I have prepared all the files, i.e. `Sample1.java, Sample1.class, Sample1.h, Sample1.cpp` and `libSample1.so`, and when I try to run the command

```
java Sample1
```

I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libSample1 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1889)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at Sample1.main(Sample1.java:10)
```

The problem line of `Sample1.java` is given as;

```
System.loadLibrary("libSample1");
```

I have read a question similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9905420/842808) and tried to take advice from one of its [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9905495/842808), i.e. added current directory to environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (current directory contains `libSample1.so` file) using;

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
```

But this still doesn't help me. Even a call to `java -XshowSettings:properties` shows that `java.library.path` contains `.` as one of the search paths.

When I replace relative file path with absolute file path by replacing `System.loadLibrary("libSample1")` with `System.load("<absolute-file-path>/libSample1.so");`, this problem goes away. Can someone tell me how to make sure that `java.library.path` can find my shared library file?

Comment: Why is this tagged `C++`?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think its unnecessary. But I did it because I am trying to call a C++ shared lib from a Java program. I thought that it might be a relevant information.

Comment: I think `.` is the current working directory of the `ld` program (the linker program) not your program.

Comment: Why don't you try to find the current working directory of your program at runtime and construct an absolute path to the library if loading it using an absolute path works ?

Comment: @Titus 
comment1) I checked the `user.dir` property in java -XshowSettings:properties and it shows me the current directory.

comment2) I can try to do that, but I still dont understand the reason for failure of this seemingly simple error.

Comment: @Titus Thanks for the temporary fix of building absolute path to file at run time. I gave up on doing it right and chose to use this hack instead.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'm not sure what the problem is, it could be any of this things. 1) The program's working directory is something other then the directory that contains the library (that depends on how you're starting the program). 2) The `String` that you pass to the  `System.loadLibrary(...)` is incorrect (I think `ld` doesn't require the `lib` prefix, you can try `System.loadLibrary("Sample1");`).

Comment: @Titus I'd also say `System.loadLibrary("Sample1")` is correct but not because of `ld` but because Java will put the parameter to `loadLibrary` through `System.mapLibraryName()`

Comment: @Abhinav Make sure so and JVM are both x86 or x64. Try this java -cp PATH_OF_JAR -Djava.library.path=PATH_TO_SO_FOLDER MAIN_CLASS